# Parsing and Inserting 10 million records into SQL

Tags: java, mysql, optimization, jdbc

So I have ~10 million records in an excel file that have to be parsed out in a specific way (I can't just convert to CSV and insert it like that) and inserted into different tables of a mysql database. I've gotten it down from taking all night to taking only a couple hours. However I would like to decrease this even further. Anyone have any tricks or tips that could help me? I'm using Java and JDBC to parse and connect.

Comment: how were you able to decrease it to a couple of hours?

Comment: Well there was a lot of inefficiencies in my code. Such as opening and closing a connection multiple times so I cut that out. I now only open one persistant connection. Also in my orignal code I loaded in all the data first then processed it all at once keeping everything in memory. Now I load it in 3 chunks and process each chunk at a time thus freeing up memory after each chunk is done. I also had some statistics that I was calculating the hard way so I cleaned those up with some hashmaps. There's probably other things but I don't have the code in front of me right now.

Comment: If the intent is to insert data from the same excel file into different tables, I'd suggest to code your own script to read from the excel file and generate INSERT statements for respective tables that can then be imported as a batch. Alternatively, your script may directly push the data into the database. The solution depends on if this import will be a one-time activity or recurring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mysql allows you to [load from a file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  Perhaps what you should do is: read 10000 records and create a file.  Start that running `load data infile` in parallel while you start reading the next 10000 records.

So this should get you closer to a fast solution:

1. Parallelize the read and load
2. Instead of indiviual inserts, use bulk data load tools

Comment: I did the same with a couple of files (400k and ~1.300k related by fk) and the loading takes tens of seconds (down from tens of minutes when using via JDBC / JPA).

Comment: If you can sort the data by primary key before `LOAD DATA INFILE`, it'll go faster as well.

Answer (score 3):

Look into using executeBatch and doing blocks of 1000 or so.  That will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

An idea...

Create a staging (temporary) database in mysql with a table called excel_staging that matches the structure of your excel file - use myisam engine for this table.

Use load data infile to load the excel file (saved as csv) into the excel_staging table - shouldn't take more than a few mins to populate especially as it's myisam.

```
truncate table excel_staging;

load data infile 'excel_staging.csv'
into table excel_staging
fields terminated by...
lines terminated by..
(
field1,
field2,
...
);
```

Write lots of select into outfile statements that extract data from the excel_staging table into individual csv files that you will use to load into your individual **innodb** production database tables. You can be really creative at this point if necessary - you may even have to load extra data to support joins etc so you can generate a nicely formatted csv output.

```
select distinct cust_id, name into outfile 'customers.csv' 
fields termniated by...
lines terminated by...
from
 excel_staging
order by
 cust_id; -- order for innodb import

select distinct dept_id, name into outfile 'departments.csv' 
fields termniated by...
lines terminated by...
from
 excel_staging
order by
 dept_id;
```

Load the nicely formatted, cleansed and orderd by primary key csv files into your production innodb tables using load data infile...

```
load data infile 'customers.csv'
into table customers
fields terminated by...
lines terminated by..
(
cust_id,
name
);

...
```

Excluding the time to code the solution (30 mins say) should be able to load into staging, output into csv and load into production tables in about ermm... 6 mins end to end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this idea I might try it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to disable foreign key checks while you're doing your inserting (only affects InnoDB), there's a pretty drastic speedup. And then of course re-enable foreign keys when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

A few JDBC performance tips, set your connection object's autoCommit to false. But make sure to commit after a significant number of inserts (every 100K or more). Also, use and reuse a PreparedStatement object over a plain Statement object.